# My media player is crashing while i play after installation for the first time. After that it is running fine

Tags: android

I am trying to play an audio file after the notification comes. But after the installation the player does not start in the first time and the app gets crashed. But from the second time it works fine.

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

```
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(path));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

```
> E/MediaPlayerNative: prepareAsync called in state 1, mPlayer(0x0)
> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main
>     Process: com.assistcrews.ally, PID: 27414
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.assistcrews.ally/com.assistcrews.ally.AudioPlayActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2944)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3079)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1836)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
>      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
>         at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
>         at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1285)
>         at com.assistcrews.ally.AudioPlayActivity.onCreate(AudioPlayActivity.java:56)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3079) 
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1836) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
```

Answer (score 0):

set `setOnPreparedListener` before calling `mediaPlayer.prepare();` or `mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();`

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
   @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        btnPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});

try {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(path));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Its having same problem after changing the code. I tried putting the OnPreparedListener after mediaPlayer.prepare(); but its not happenning.
Any other Suggestions

Comment: put OnPreparedListener before mediaPlayer.prepare()

Comment: I did the same as you said, but now the problem changed. the problem is now that the first time it runs fine but after first time it gets crashed all the time... please help me..@shb